# Thymleaf setting up value for dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Good Morning,
I am running into an issue where my value is turning out to be the text. I tried multiple different things to make my value different from the display text, but none of them are working. Can somebody give me some guidance on where I am going wrong?

```
<option th:if="${shipMethod1 != 'Unknown'}"><span th:value="${shipValue1}" th:text="${shipMethod1}"></span></option>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was being dumb... you cant have a value inside of a span.